Second Display not detected in Windows 11
I recently upgraded to Windows 11 on my PC and encountered an issue where the second display is not being detected. Before the upgrade, both displays were working fine under Windows 10. The primary display is working without any issues, but the second display remains undetected by the system. I've checked the connections and tried different cables, but the problem persists.
I've tried several troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue:

Ensured that both the graphics card drivers and Windows 11 are up to date.
Checked the display settings in Windows to see if the second monitor is recognized, but it's not listed.
Tested the second display on another computer, and it works without any issues, ruling out a hardware problem with the display itself.
Tried different output ports on the graphics card (HDMI, DisplayPort) to connect the second display.
Attempted to update the graphics card drivers and even rolled back to previous versions to see if that would resolve the issue, but it didn't.

I expected that after trying these steps, Windows 11 would detect the second display and allow me to extend or duplicate my desktop as usual. However, none of these attempts have been successful.

try disconnecting the first display

@jsotola The first display is the primary display of the laptop.
I also tried selecting the second screen only option from the Win + P menu, but nothing worked.

the laptop might use a hotkey

Does the laptop natively support Windows 11 or did you have to modify or trick that OS into installing? What is your specific laptop model? In addition to graphics drivers, go to your Laptop's official support site and download and install any other drivers and firmware available there, and probably any hotkey utilities as well. Did you check the laptop support site for documented issues of the sort you're seeing?

@music2myear Hey, thanks for your response.
Yes, my laptop natively supports Windows 11. I was previously on Windows 10, and it upgraded to 11 automatically after installing some Windows updates.
It's an HP Elite x360 1040 G5. I've tried downloading and installing the graphics driver from the official HP website. I've explored tons of resources and documentation, but nothing works.
The external display worked with my other laptop running Windows 10, and I also have one more display that isn't working with this HP laptop.
All I can think of is driver issues or bugs in Windows 11.

Here is the complete details of my system: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/jwabDr4TBcHmKvgqcmudfHe

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/153854/hp-elitebook-x360-g2-1030-looses-ability-to-connec
